# hiding/showing trigger dynamically for a combobox in extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox

I want to know is there any way to hide/show the trigger dynamically for a combo box in extjs?

Could anyone please suggest the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used combo.triggerEl.hide() or combo.triggerEl.show(). It worked for me. Thanks for the help Sra.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use the [`hideTrigger`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-hideTrigger) config property of the combobox. If you need to do it dynamically after the combo is rendered you can do something like this:

(The following is done this way because of a bug that messed up the width when more then one trigger is used. Last known bugged version 4.1.3)

```
onShowTrigger: function (show) {
    if (show) {
        this.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
            if (i === 0) { // the ident of the trigger. will start with 0
                el.setWidth(el.originWidth, false);
                el.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
            if (i === 0) {
                el.originWidth = el.getWidth();
                el.setWidth(0, false);
                el.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }
    // Version specific methods
    if (Ext.lastRegisteredVersion.shortVersion > 407) {
        this.updateLayout();
    } else {
        this.updateEditState();
    }
}
```

Exit

The code above should be implemented within a extension of a combobox like

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.CustomCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.customcombo',

    onShowTrigger: function (show) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Where you can call this method by yourself like

```
var combo = Ext.widget('customcombo');
combo.onShowTrigger(false);
```

Comment: Can I know the listener onShowTrigger is available for combo box or not?

Comment: Thanks for the help Sra. I just included the line "combo.triggerEl.hide()"/ "combo.triggerEl.show()". It worked for me.

Comment: @ramyasri Well this solution above is/was for all versions lower 4.2  Because there was a bug that caused to mess up the size if there are more then one trigger